# APACHE2: avoid https:// REDIRECT to open phpmyadmin

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, https, apache2, phpmyadmin

I have a site `https://example.com`to ensure that all users go to the https:// I set up a redirect with APACHE (on the default.conf) as followed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com
        # DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

My issue is when I try to access my phpmyadmin `example.net/phpmyadmin` I redirect to `https://example.net/phpmyadmin` and the page cannot be displayed.
(It is obviously working if I remove the Redirect).
How can I get avoid the redirect only for my phpmyadmin?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [disable ForceSSL within PHPMyAdmin](http://thebarton.org/forcing-ssl-with-phpmyadmin/) but there's a reason why its forced and this is to make the connection more secure. I recommend that you move to doing redirects using [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rather than using virtualhost method, by doing so you have more control on your redirects for each of your web applications.

In `/var/www/.htaccess` it should look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

then in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess` use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was trying to avoid mod_rewrite has it is said to be only a last resort solution http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/avoid.html. But your solution seems really nice too.

Comment: "redirects using mod_rewrite rather than using virtualhost method" - I think this should be "mod_alias" rather than "virtualhost"? You can use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) in a VirtualHost context just as you could use mod_alias (`Redirect`).

Answer (score 0):

A way around: 
I do not know why but if I type as url `example.net/phpmyadmin` I will be redirected to `https://example.netphpmyadmin/` but if I write `https://example.net/phpmyadmin/` (with the **/**)I go to php my admin.
No idea why but I hope it will be of help to others.

to force https:// on pyp myadmin I added: `$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;` at the end of phpMyAdmin’s config.inc.php file (see http://thebarton.org/forcing-ssl-with-phpmyadmin/).